# How to properly assign Kivy label text from Python file?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, kivy

I'm pretty new to Kivy and Python so apologies for any glaring error.

I'm trying to make a home screen which displays the name used to login on the previous screen.  Code snippets as follows:

My main app class;

```
class ProDuck(App):  
    logged_in_user = StringProperty()  
    print(logged_in_user)  
    def build(self):  
        self.icon = "LogoIcon.png"  
        GUI = Builder.load_file("GUI.kv")  
        return GUI
```

(Correctly formatted with indentation though)

Part of the login which changes the StringProperty,  which inside another screen class.  The logging_in_user is from self.username.text within that screen class;

```
    if attempt == target_pass_hash[0]:
        print("Login successful!")
        print(logging_in_user)
        ProDuck.logged_in_user = logging_in_user
        print("New variable = " + ProDuck.logged_in_user)
```

Relevant part of .kv file;

```
GridLayout:  
  
    Label:  
        id: nametag  
        text: app.logged_in_user  #<---  
        color: "grey"
```

The app runs, and prints the right variables, however the label which gets displayed is blank.  I am really not sure why the label is not showing any text, am I assigning the StringProperty wrong in the login part?  Appreciate any help :)

Comment: I edited your post to improve the formatting. Is the `Label` in the `.kv` file intended to be a child of the `GridLayout`?

Comment: Yes, apologies the formatting was wrong on the post but correct in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `ProDuck.logged_in_user` is not the correct way to access a `Property`. You need to reference it through the instance of `ProDuck`. One way to do that is to use `App.get_running_app().logged_in_user`. So your code block could be:

```
if attempt == target_pass_hash[0]:
    print("Login successful!")
    print(logging_in_user)
    App.get_running_app().logged_in_user = logging_in_user
    print("New variable = " + App.get_running_app().logged_in_user)
```

Comment: Thank you so much John, this fixed it for me.  If you don't mind me asking, is that because I was referencing the class of the app not the actual instance of it?